# Firefox 6 HTML audio.duration = NaN problem

Tags: javascript, html, firefox, html5-audio, firefox6

I just found a possible bug in Firefox 6 for Windows. When I try to get the audio.duration value in a function that triggered by audio "loadeddata" event, in Firefox 6 for Windows, the value is NaN. And the audio.duration value updates with the audio.currentTime value while audio starts playing (audio.duration == audio.currentTime).

This only happens in Firefox 6 for Windows. I tried the same javascript code in Safari, Chrome, Firefox 6 (on Mac OS X 10.7) and Chrome, IE 9 (on Windows 7), it works fine. So it seems the problem only occurs on Firefox 6 for Windows. The audio for Firefox is ogg format. Does anyone else find this problem?

Comment: If you found a bug then you should file it under https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/enter_bug.cgi?product=Core (Component: Video/Audio). What kind of answer do you expect here?

Comment: Sorry, I just want someone can test it as well to make sure if this is exactly a bug in Firefox 6.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have sorted out this problem by providing audios with CBR encoding. For VBR encoded audios, audio.duration always get NaN in Firefox 6/7/8 for Windows.